# gridview paging in popup

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am Working in ASP.NET and c#.

I have gridview which i am binding on a button click,also am showing this gridview in popup.Now paging is not working in my gridview ,please help me out to solve this problem.

Aspx:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GV_Order" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false"   DataKeyNames="ProductCode" EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display."
        BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" 
        CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2"
        HeaderStyle-BackColor="Black" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#FFD700" PageSize="5" OnPageIndexChanging="GV_Orderpageindexchanging" o>
```

codebehind:

```
  protected void btn_click(object sender,eventargs e)
  {
    GV_Order.DataSource = dataset;
    GV_Order.DataBind();
  }

   protected void GV_Orderpageindexchanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
   {
    GV_Order.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GV_Order.DataBind();
   }
```

Comment: In the GV_Orderpageindexchanging event,you have to bind with the datasource.GV_Order.DataSource = dataset; you have missed this line.

Comment: what do you mean by popup. Is it a new window or on the same page a division which opens like a pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

asp.net DataPager control is not usefull,use [Jquery Data Table](http://www.datatables.net/) for this.its realy nice working for all table.
add 'datatable' class to which table you want to use  'paging', 'searching','ordering'..  plugins ,